# Equivalent of String.Format in a Chef/Bash Recipe

Tags: linux, chef-infra

looking for something similar to .Net string format in a chef recipe ie.

```
string phone = String.format("phone: {0}",_phone);
```

I have a Chef recipe where I need to build up a command string with 30 of these params so hoping for a tidy way to build the string, in principle Im doing this

```
a=node['some_var'].to_s
ruby_block "run command" do
  block do
    cmd = shell_out!("node mycommand.js #{a}; exit 2;")           
  end
end
```

When I try this I get the error

**Arguments to path.join must be strings** any tips appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? It really sounds like a XY problem where you try to solve something unrelated to what you wish accomplished at end in fact. (And why on hell using a `exit 2` on any execution ?)

Comment: I want to pass parameters to a node app which is inside a chef recipe - thats it. The shell_out! is sending the output back to my CI server. ignore the exit 2.

Comment: That sounds a bad idea (you should log locally and eventually dump the log on screen at end of run IMHO). Anyway, without knowing what you're giving in `node['some_var']` it's quite hard to guess what could go wrong here. I highly suspect the command line sanytizing process to hang on the ; but I'm unsure. (source code [here](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout/blob/master/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef runs in two phases:

Compile and Execute (see https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/09/04/demystifying-common-idioms-in-chef-recipes/ for more details).

Your variable assignment to `a` happens at compile time, e.g. when chef loads all recipes. The ruby block will be execute in execution mode at converge time and cannot access the variable `a`.

So the easiest solution might be putting the attribute into the ruby block:

```
   ruby_block "run command with argument #{node['some_var']}" do
     block do
       shell_out!("node mycommand.js #{node['some_var']}")
     end
   end
```

**However:**

1. If you don't need to execute Ruby code, consider using the `execute` or `bash` resource instead.
2. Keep in mind, that you must have a unique resource name, if you're building some kind of loop around it. An easy way is to put something unique into the name `ruby_block "something unique per loop iteration" do ... end`
3. What I really don't understand is your exit code 2. This is an error code. It will make chef throw an exception each time. (`shell_out!` throws an exception if exit code != 0, see https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb#L24-L28)
4. The resource will be executed on each chef run. This is probably not in your interest. Consider adding a guard (test), to prevent unnecessary execution, see https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards